# Find out cause of strange highlight in Vim

Tags: vim

I am using latexbox in vim for latex file editing. I found that some words such as "vertices", "Online" "i.e." are highlighted in light blue. Is there any way to find out the rule why Vim makes such strange highlight? I would simply want to disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find the culprit to the problem.

The strange highlight comes from the spell check of vim classifying my text as SpellCap.

To fix this I just need to use

```
hi clear SpellCap
```

Or you can change it to a less annoying color

```
highlight SpellCap term=underline cterm=underline
```

Answer (score 1):

For this, the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin is indispensable. It'll show you the syntax group under the cursor. You can then disable that (preferably in `~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim`, using `:syntax clear {group-name}`).

Comment: when I find out it is a "texDocZone"
calling "syntax clear texDocZone" gives a group not found error
but simply calling "syntax clear" solves the problem...

Answer (score 0):

To turn syntax highlighting off, just use this command: `:syntax off`.

You can find out, which syntax file is used for your file by entering `:set syntax`.

To get further help on this topic enter `:help syntax`.